# UITableView content hugging

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I’ve a `UITableView`that hugs it’s content when a UILabel appears. The following images shows what I mean:

Before UILabel appeareance

[image: Before UILabel appeareance]

After UILabel appearance

[image: After UILabel appearance]

I tried to set the UITableView content hugging priority lower then the others views but it grows too much. Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

This is my current views hierachy:

[image: Views hierarchy]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Oh sorry. I want that simply the UITableView go under the UILabel and I don't want to that the UITableView become scrollable.

Comment: Ciao Pairon, which are the tableview constraints?

Comment: Ciao Kerberos, the UITableView doesn't have their own constraints because all the views that you see in the images are embedded in a UIStackView.

Comment: do you have a scrollview -> stackview -> tableview?

Comment: @Edudjr see my update. If isn't enough clear: I've a ScrollView > ContentView > StackView > Stack View > 3 Stack Views

Comment: You don't have a tableview, onlys stackViews?

Comment: @SergioTrejo Nope, my UITableView is inside "Dishes Table View Stack View".